# __stack_chk_fail in SKNode subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, sprite-kit, sknode

I have attempted to create an SKNode subclass for a node that will be called repeatedly, each time with a user interaction, then an breaking/explosion effect. However, whenever I try to run the code, I receive a SIGABRT error. Something to do with `___stack_chk_fail` in the debug terminal.

Additionally, in the inspector, when the code breaks for the SIGABRT, all of these properties are displayed as `nil`.

This is the .m of my SKNode subclass:

```
#import "CandyNode.h"

static const int MAX_VELOCITY = 20;
static const int MIN_VELOCITY = 2;

@implementation CandyNode

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self == [super init])
    {
        _spriteType = arc4random()%4+1;
        NSString* imageRand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sprite %i", _spriteType];

        _background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:imageRand];
        _background.name = @"Main";
        _background.zPosition = 3;
        [self addChild:_background];

        _burst1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%dB%d",_spriteType,1]];
        _burst2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%dB%d",_spriteType,2]];
        _burst3 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%dB%d",_spriteType,3]];

        _burst1.name = @"Burst #1";
        _burst2.name = @"Burst #2";
        _burst3.name = @"Burst #3";

        [_background setHidden:NO];

        [_burst1 setHidden:YES];
        [_burst2 setHidden:YES];
        [_burst3 setHidden:YES];

        [self addChild:_burst1];
        [self addChild:_burst2];
        [self addChild:_burst3];

        double burstAngle[3];
        int offsetAngle = 240;
        double burstDisplacement[3];
        CGVector burstVector[3];

        CGFloat x, y;
        for (int i = 0; i<=3; i++){
            burstAngle[i] = (arc4random()%60+120*i+offsetAngle)*3.1415/180;
            burstDisplacement[i] = arc4random()%(MAX_VELOCITY-MIN_VELOCITY)+ MIN_VELOCITY;
            x = burstDisplacement[i]*cos(burstAngle[i]);
            y = burstDisplacement[i]*sin(burstAngle[i]);
            burstVector[i] = CGVectorMake(x, y);
        }

        _explode1 = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction fadeInWithDuration:0],
                                         [SKAction moveBy:burstVector[0] duration:.5],
                                         [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:.2]]];
        _explode2 = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction fadeInWithDuration:0],
                                         [SKAction moveBy:burstVector[1] duration:.5],
                                         [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:.2]]];
        _explode3 = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction fadeInWithDuration:0],
                                         [SKAction moveBy:burstVector[2] duration:.5],
                                         [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:.2]]];

    }
    return self;

}
```

.h:

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
@interface CandyNode : SKNode

//-(id)initWithImageNumber:(int)spriteType;
//-(void)explodeCandy;

@property (nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *background;
@property (nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *burst1;
@property (nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *burst2;
@property (nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *burst3;

@property (nonatomic) SKAction *explode1;
@property (nonatomic) SKAction *explode2;
@property (nonatomic) SKAction *explode3;

@property (nonatomic) int spriteType;


@end
```

And it is all called in a main SKScene with: `_NodeA = [CandyNode new];`, _NodeA being defined in that class's header as `@property (nonatomic) CandyNode *NodeA;`

My question is obviously how can I get this to work, or if I have a horrible misunderstanding of how to use subclasses and SpriteKit, how can I do this differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling init twice:

```
self = [super init];
if (self == [super init])
```

The first correctly assigns to self, the second creates an instance, compares it with self, then throws the new instance away.

To fix this:

```
self = [super init];
if (self)
```

**UPDATE:**

You declare an array with 3 elements:

```
double burstAngle[3];
```

Then you enumerate over the array with a range of 0 to 3 (for loop runs four times):

```
for (int i = 0; i<=3; i++){
```

When i is 3 you have an index out of bounds situation, array indexes are zero-based.

Fix it like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
```

Comment: That's not the issue. Oddly enough, [super init] returns the same instance when called twice.

Comment: Thanks. It was the index out of bounds that fixed it. The sure don't make the error message intuitive about it though.

Comment: well, that's what you get from you're using C arrays ;)